# Can I sum an array of jsonb in Postgresql with dynamic keys in a select statement?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have a jsonb object in postgres:

```
[{"a": 1, "b":5}, {"a":2, "c":3}]
```

I would like to get an aggregate sum per unique key:

```
{"a":3, "b":5, "c":3}
```

The keys are unpredictable.

Is it possible to do this in Postgres with a select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT key, SUM(value::INTEGER)
FROM (
  SELECT (JSONB_EACH_TEXT(j)).*
  FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS('[{"a": 1, "b":5}, {"a":2, "c":3}]') j
) j
GROUP BY key
ORDER BY key;
```

Results:

```
| key | sum |
| --- | --- |
| a   | 3   |
| b   | 5   |
| c   | 3   |
```

---

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mrR3u9NMw5jmgCYG2AzdSb/0)